# Salesforce Lightning automation with puppeteer (through Lightning Data Service?)

Tags: javascript, salesforce, puppeteer

Has anyone experience with automating Salesforce Lightning web interface with puppeteer? No element IDs, just shadow DOM, looks possible only through image recognition or direct JavaScript API calls.

I see AuraInstance under $A variable (reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_intro.htm)
I have installed https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/inspector_use.htm and see component tree

Any idea how to get access from JavaScript to Lightning Data Service (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data.htm)?

1. Using browser's network activity I have found an URL that is doing the job which I could reuse:
   https://***.lightning.force.com/aura?r=34&ui-force-components-controllers-recordGlobalValueProvider.RecordGvp.saveQuickActionRecords=1
   with a payload of:

`{"actions":[{"id":"2320;a","descriptor":"serviceComponent://ui.force.components.controllers.recordGlobalValueProvider.RecordGvpController/ACTION$saveQuickActionRecords","callingDescriptor":"UNKNOWN","params":{"record":{"apiName":"Event","childRelationships":{},"eTag":"df51c121372ca57e0fbe094d4fba0d1c","fields":{"Activity_Type__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":"Call"},"CountsAgainstTarget__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":""},"Description":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"EndDateTime":{"displayValue":null,"value":"2023-04-29T09:30:00.000Z"},"OwnerId":{"displayValue":null,"value":"005b0000006KeOSAA0"},"RecordTypeId":{"displayValue":null,"value":"012b0000000Dga3AAC"},"StartDateTime":{"displayValue":null,"value":"2023-04-29T09:00:00.000Z"},"Subject":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"VisitType__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":"Customer Visit"},"What":{"displayValue":null,"value":{"apiName":"Account","fields":{"Name":{"value":""}},"recordTypeInfo":null}},"WhatId":{"displayValue":null,"value":""},"Who":{"displayValue":null,"value":{"apiName":"Contact","fields":{"Name":{"value":""}},"recordTypeInfo":null}},"WhoId":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"WhoCount":{"value":null,"displayValue":null}},"id":null,"lastModifiedById":null,"lastModifiedDate":null,"recordTypeId":"012b0000000Dga3AAC","recordTypeInfo":{"available":true,"defaultRecordTypeMapping":true,"master":false,"name":"Event","recordTypeId":"012b0000000Dga3AAC"},"systemModstamp":null,"weakEtag":0},"quickActionName":"NewEvent","contextIds":["005b0000006KeOSAA0"],"fetchFeedItem":true,"recordSaveParams":{"bypassDedupeCheck":false,"triggerAutoResponseEmail":false,"triggerOtherEmail":false,"triggerUserEmail":false,"isAllOrNothing":false,"filterInvalidFields":true,"useDefaultRule":false,"publishEngagementEvent":true,"skipCurrencyConversion":true}}}]}`

plus some other which I can most probably trace within cookies. The problem is with the action's ID ("2320;a" above) which seems to be unique and different on each request. Any idea how to obtain next action ID?

or

2. How to obtain field IDs for generated content? For example I have a dynamic HTML id of "combobox-input-144" (changed for every request) for event's subject - how to map it to "evt5" which is id of event's subject in classic salesforce?

Comment: This is rather broad. Open shadow roots can be pierced by Puppeteer... but what are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Fill and submit new event or order forms